# bijective function with powerset and symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $X$ a set and $Y\subseteq X$ and

$$f: \mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X),\text{ with }A\in \mathcal{P}(X)\mapsto A\,\Delta\, Y$$

($\Delta:=$ exclusive disjunction)

Show that $f$ is bijective and find the inverse $f^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm very confused, why do you have the Weierstrass $\wp$ function applied to $X$?

Comment: @AdamHughes: I believe he is using that notation for the power set of $X$.

Comment: Ah! to the op: $\wp$ has the code \wp because it means Weierstrass P, you probably want to just use \mathcal{P} or P for powerset, or at least indicate in your post what your notation means.

Comment: @Adam Hughes yes Clayton is right, sorry I thought it was that symbol for powerset

Comment: It is obvious, isn't it. check well defined.

Comment: @Adam: In some places $\wp$ is used to denote the power set operation.

Comment: Those for whom the following remark on typesetting is too nitpicking are hereby ordered not to read it unless they want to: There is not as much space between "$+$" and "$b$" in $+b$ as there is in $a+b$, because TeX and all its successor softwares put some space to the right and left of binary operators like "$+$".  But $\Delta$ is not in the software's list of things used as a binary operator so I think the spacing should be added manually, thus A\,\Delta\,Y, yielding $A\,\Delta\,Y$. I edited the question accordingly. In things like $a\,\Delta x$ I use that spacing on the left but...

Comment: ....not on the right, since the thing is being used in that context as essentially a unary operator.  Likewise in $\Delta h\,\Delta p$ I put a small space between $h$ and $\Delta$ but not between $\Delta$ and the succeeding character.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You could use \mathbin for that, as in A\mathbin{\Delta}Y or A\mathbin{\triangle}Y, yielding $A\mathbin{\Delta}Y$ or $A\mathbin{\triangle}Y$ respectively.